# Completar celda en Google sheets ÚNICAMENTE con los valores de un dropdown

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una fila en Google Sheets que cuenta con un Dropdown con 5 opciones, por ejemplo:

-Emmanuel
-Laura
-Camila
-Jorge
-Matias

¿Existe la forma de hacer que estas celdas únicamente puedan tener esos 5 valores y que no se le permita que escriban algo fuera de ese rango como por ejemplo "fiorella"?

No puedo bloquear permisos de edición de la hoja porque hay otras filas en las que sí necesito que escriban texto.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.